# Object of multiple arrays into single object with single array of objects

Tags: php

**Update**: This has still not been solved, so all help is appreciated!

**Please note**: I stripped out all the unnecessary items and left just the bare minimum needed.

So here I have the following foreach loop inside my method:

```
$data = [];
foreach($this->get_authenticated_users() as $user) {
    .....
    ... Please note: I removed the non-needed code ...
    .....
    $data[] = json_decode($json_data);
}
var_dump($data);
```

So let's say that I have `var_dump($data)` which gives me the following output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2503 (2) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2477 (6) {
        ["timestamp"]=>
        string(24) "2022-02-23T01:26:50+0000"
        ["id"]=>
        string(17) "17899959194451041"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2499 (2) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2476 (6) {
        ["timestamp"]=>
        string(24) "2022-02-20T19:41:17+0000"
        ["id"]=>
        string(17) "1789995915463041"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to convert the array into a single object, so I use the following `foreach` outside of the original `foreach` such as this:

```
$data = [];
foreach($this->get_authenticated_users() as $user) {
    .....
    ... Please note: I removed the non-needed code ...
    .....
    $data[] = json_decode($json_data);
}
foreach ($data as $key => $single_data) {
    $merged_data[$key] = $single_data->data;
}
var_dump($merged_data);
```

Where `var_dump($merged_data)` is the `["data"]` of `$data` which outputs the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2473 (6) {
      ["timestamp"]=>
      string(24) "2022-02-23T01:26:50+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "17899959194451041"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2472 (6) {
      ["timestamp"]=>
      string(24) "2022-02-20T19:41:17+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "17956063417578984"
    }
  }
}
```

So this isn't the outcome that I want, I want the outcome to be more along these lines:

```
object(stdClass)#2498 (2) {
    ["data"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#2472 (6) {
                ["id"]=> string(17) "17956063417578984"
                ["timestamp"]=> string(24) "2022-02-20T19:41:17+0000"
        }
        [1]=> object(stdClass)#2472 (6) {
                ["id"]=> string(17) "17956063417578984"
                ["timestamp"]=> string(24) "2022-02-23T01:26:50+0000"
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone spot what I might be doing wrong in my execution?

Comment: can you please var_export the array after decoding* and maybe to put 'true' as 2nr argument of the method json_decode()

Comment: I think you remove too much, as its not as irrelevant as you may think

Comment: @AngelDeykov, I did, the output of `json_decode()` is `var_dump($data)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have Lots of unnecessary code, I would be more sure if I could see some of the irrelevant code, but this is basically what I think you can do to achieve what you want in a lot less code.

```
$data = new stdClass();
foreach($this->get_authenticated_users() as $user) {
    .....
    ... Please note: I removed the non-needed code ...
    .....
    
    $data->data[] = json_decode($json_data);
}
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Does the inner foreach code go after the json_decode or before?

Comment: I have a `cURL` request that was stripped out because others have mentioned that it was not relevant and have downvoted posts before, but it does have a `cURL` request inside the foreach, that's why the json decode was included.

Comment: How does $o know about the data in `$json_data` is the response from the API? Serious question as I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Show me the missing code and then I can make use of the right data. At least how you put data into the `$json_data` variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242376/discussion-between-sle-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 0):

Now lets go over what happens. Your input data for the for loop is the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2473 (6) {
      ["timestamp"]=>
      string(24) "2022-02-23T01:26:50+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "17899959194451041"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2472 (6) {
      ["timestamp"]=>
      string(24) "2022-02-20T19:41:17+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "17956063417578984"
    }
  }
}
```

Your for loop iterates over every entry and gets key and value. An entry of this array is:

```
[0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2503 (2) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2477 (6) {
        ["timestamp"]=>
        string(24) "2022-02-23T01:26:50+0000"
        ["id"]=>
        string(17) "17899959194451041"
      }
    }
  }
```

The key of this entry is 0, that explains why your output array an entry with key 0. You also take the contents of "data" of your entry and put it inside this new entry of your output array. The the content of "data" is the following:

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2477 (6) {
        ["timestamp"]=>
        string(24) "2022-02-23T01:26:50+0000"
        ["id"]=>
        string(17) "17899959194451041"
      }
    }
```

If you now put these things together, you place the "data" value into a new array at key 0, which looks like this:

```
[0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2473 (6) {
      ["timestamp"]=>
      string(24) "2022-02-23T01:26:50+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(17) "17899959194451041"
    }
  }
```

This is exactly what you observe.

Your for loop would have to look like this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $single_data) {
    $merged_data[$key] = $single_data->data[0];
}
```

The problem was, that "data" contains an array, but you want to access the first entry of that array. After that, you have to place the new output array inside another stdClass object to achieve your wanted data structure.

Comment: So after making that change, I'm still getting the output as an array and not object of array of objects, but this is good knowledge!

Comment: merged_data is an array, thats why the output is an array. Thats why i mentioned at the end of my answer, that you have to place the output array into a new object of stdClass. Something like this: $o = (new stdClass())->setData($merged_data);

Comment: Do let me know when a strClass got a `setData()` method :)

Comment: Yeah, sry, my mistake. Was thinking to general. The way to do it would be:
$o = new stdClass();
$o->data = $merged_data

Comment: @Tobias, I tried to follow this more clearly, but I can't seem to figure it out, can you post an update with a answer if possible?

Comment: @SLE sorry, i don't quite get your current problem. Could you explain what is not working at the moment? After the for loop, your $merged_data should look like the array inside the "data" key of your wanted data structure. It should look something like this: array(2) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)...
Am I right in this assumption?

Comment: @Tobias, the aim that I'm going for is `Object { ["data"] => { object { ..... }, object { ..... }`.

Comment: @SLE and what is the problem? I still don't know how your $merged_data looks like. var_dump will never output what you just specified. $merged_data should look something like the array inside the "data" key, but it will always be an array, as it has no named keys